# how to have three different lists print on one line

Tags: python, list, random

I want to print three different lists, **with random choices**, all onto one line. How would I do this?
This is my code so far:

```
numbers = list(range(1, 50)) 
operators = ["+", "-", "x"] 
numbers1 = list(range(1,10)) 
print(random.choice(numbers))   
print(random.choice(operators)) 
print(random.choice(numbers1))
```

Comment: How would I make this become a question that a user needs to input an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import random    

numbers = list(range(1, 50)) 
operators = ["+", "-", "x"] 
numbers1 = list(range(1,10))

print(str(random.choice(numbers)) + random.choice(operators) + str(random.choice(numbers1)))
```

The numbers are converted to strings first.

Answer (score 0):

You could comma separate the arguments to `print` to print a `tuple`, or you could use a format string to print the random choices as part of a string:

```
import random

numbers = list(range(1, 50))
operators = ["+", "-", "x"]
numbers1 = list(range(1,10))
print(random.choice(numbers), random.choice(operators), random.choice(numbers1))
print('{} {} {}'.format(random.choice(numbers), random.choice(operators), random.choice(numbers)))
```

**Sample Output**

```
(18, 'x', 1)
10 + 30
```

Answer (score 0):

One line output:

```
print "number: {0} operator: {1} number1: {2}".format(random.choice(numbers), random.choice(operators), random.choice(numbers1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to add everything you need with the order you want to one variable, and just print the variable.

Answer (score 0):

to make it short:

```
print map(random.choice, (numbers, operators, numbers1))
```